# Reducing arrow margin in chemfig

Tags: margins, arrows, chemfig

Im trying to get a figure with a chemfig drawing to fit in my column. I cannot scale the entire figure with scalebox, as the text set with \chemname{} will be scaled too.

[image]

```
\setatomsep{1.2em}
\setbondoffset{0.1em} % 'Margin Width'
\setarrowdefault{,0.6,}


\definesubmol{hydroxy}[HO]{OH}

\definesubmol{foo}{
    -[::180,2,,,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt]O
    -[::60]
    =[::-60]
    -[::60](-[::-60]R)
    =[::60]
    -[::60](-[::-60]!{hydroxy})
    =[::60](
        -[::-60]O
        -[::60,1.5,,,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt]
    )
    -[::60]
}

\definesubmol{bar}{
    -[::180,2,,,draw=none]!{hydroxy}
    -[::60]
    =[::-60]
    -[::60](-[::-60]R)
    =[::60]
    -[::60](-[::-60]!{hydroxy})
    =[::60](
        -[::-60]!{hydroxy}
    )
    -[::60]
}

\schemestart
\chemname{
\chemfig[][scale=.5]{
    Fe
    (!{foo})
    ([::120]!{bar})
    ([::240]!{bar})
}
}{Mono}
\arrow{<=>[pH]}
\chemname{
\chemfig[][scale=.5]{
    Fe
    (!{foo})
    ([::120]!{foo})
    ([::240]!{bar})
}
}{Bis}
\arrow{<=>[pH]}
\chemname{
\chemfig[][scale=.5]{
    Fe
    (!{foo})
    ([::120]!{foo})
    ([::240]!{foo})
}
}{Tris}
\schemestop
```

I would like to reduce the spacing on each side of the arrows so it leaves some more space for either scaling the molecules, or making more room for the "pH" text.

Comment: If you're using `chemfig`'s `\schemestart ... \arrow ... \schemestop` then `\setarrowoffset{<dim>}` is what you want

Comment: Thanks for the help @clemens, you pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to do this using clemens' comment, and some help from the chemfig manual.

I added the follow lines:

```
\setcompoundsep{1.5em}
\setarrowoffset{1pt}
```

And the result:

[image]

```
\setatomsep{1.2em}
\setbondoffset{0.1em}
\setcompoundsep{1.5em}
\setarrowoffset{1pt}

\definesubmol{hydroxy}[HO]{OH}

\definesubmol{foo}{
    -[::180,2,,,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt]O
    -[::60]
    =[::-60]
    -[::60](-[::-60]R)
    =[::60]
    -[::60](-[::-60]!{hydroxy})
    =[::60](
        -[::-60]O
        -[::60,1.5,,,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt]
    )
    -[::60]
}

\definesubmol{bar}{
    -[::180,2,,,draw=none]!{hydroxy}
    -[::60]
    =[::-60]
    -[::60](-[::-60]R)
    =[::60]
    -[::60](-[::-60]!{hydroxy})
    =[::60](
        -[::-60]!{hydroxy}
    )
    -[::60]
}

\schemestart
\chemname{
\chemfig[][scale=.6]{
    Fe
    (!{foo})
    ([::120]!{bar})
    ([::240]!{bar})
}
}{Mono}
\arrow{<=>[pH]}
\chemname{
\chemfig[][scale=.6]{
    Fe
    (!{foo})
    ([::120]!{foo})
    ([::240]!{bar})
}
}{Bis}
\arrow{<=>[pH]}
\chemname{
\chemfig[][scale=.6]{
    Fe
    (!{foo})
    ([::120]!{foo})
    ([::240]!{foo})
}
}{Tris}
\schemestop
```