# Reduce the gap between arrow and molecule (node) in chemfig scheme

Tags: chemfig

I have the following scheme.

```
\documentclass[crop,trim]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{FiraSans}
\usepackage[small]{eulervm}
%\usepackage{opensans}
%\usepackage{mathpazo}

\begin{document}

% Remove margins from tabular. Don't know how it works but see 
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116784/8087
\begin{tabular*}{5cm}{@{}l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r@{}}
   \schemestart
       X \arrow{->}[0,0.75] X\textsuperscript{*}
   \schemestop\label{reac:phospho}
   \\
   \schemestart
       X\textsuperscript{*} + P \arrow{<->>}[0,0.75]  X\textsuperscript{*}P
       \arrow{->}[0,0.7] X + P
   \schemestop\label{reac:depospho}
\end{tabular*}
\end{document}
```

I get the following:

[image: scheme]

There is quite a white-space between node and arrow. I want to reduce this space so that this fits into margin for document. How to reduce this gap?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/279354/8087 offers a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

like this?

[image]

i redesign table. now has only one column, not two, and instead `tabular*` is used `tabular`. also i made arrows slightly shorter:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{FiraSans}
\usepackage[small]{eulervm}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

% Remove margins from tabular. Don't know how it works but see
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116784/8087
\begin{tabular}{@{} l @{}}
   \schemestart
X \arrow{->}[0,0.5] X\textsuperscript{*}
   \schemestop\label{reac:phospho}
   \\
   \schemestart
X\textsuperscript{*} + P \arrow{<->>}[0,0.5]  X\textsuperscript{*}P \arrow{->}[0,0.5] X + P%
   \schemestop\label{reac:depospho}
\end{tabular}
```

as you can see, the preamble is reorganized too. (`mathtools` load `amsmath`, and `pgfplots` load `tikz`, so it is sufficient to load only the firs packages.

Comment: Thanks. I can see the gap reduced but can't see what actually changed in the code. Does it rely on single column tabular? 

I found this https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/279354/8087 which is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Dilawar, than wrote own answer ...

Comment: I am sorry but I didn't mean to belittle your effort and help. I just wanted to point out the solution I found at other link was clearer to me.

Comment: @Dilawar, no you not belittle me. my answer still solve some (off topic) problems, which is worth to consider ...  if you find solution for your main problem, than please share it with others here with answer. you can also accept it and with this emphasize its importance.